# Berryboot fallback partition

Tags: berryboot

Berryboot is a great way to load multiple os's onto a single pi, but I'd like to use it for something very specific.

I need to be able to have berryboot attempt to load the default os, and if it crashes, fallback to a backup clone (which will already be there in the menu). I would also like to be able to change the default booted os from within one of the operating systems, if this is at all possible, but this would just be a nice add-on.

The kicker is, it needs to be able to do all of this automatically. This is because the purpose of this is for the pi to be able to be updated remotely without fear of an update crash taking it down for any long period of time.

As for the os, I'm willing to change os's to make this work, so any os that's on berryboot will work.

Is it possible for berryboot to be programmed like this? If so, how?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm looking for a golden image solution as well for remote RPi applications.